# How to change Style of the next characters that will be typed in JTextPane

Tags: java, eclipse, jtextpane

I have a problem, I am not able to change style for next characters that will be typed in `JTextPane`, so I don't want to change Style for whole `JTextPane`, but only for next characters.
For example if I use this:

```
tekst.getStyledDocument().setCharacterAttributes(0, tekst.getStyledDocument().getLength() + 1, at, false);
```

whole text is styled, but I don't want this to happen.

Can anyone tell me what to do.

I am trying to change style from my cursor position to future letters entered in JTextPane

```
 tekst1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            selektovaniTxt = tekst1.getSelectedText();
            pozicija = tekst1.getCaretPosition();
            System.out.println("Pozicija je: "+pozicija);

            //some style
            Style st1= tekst1.addStyle("default1", null);
            StyleConstants.setFontSize(st1, new Integer(30));
            StyleConstants.setFontFamily(st1, "Verdana");

               tekst1.getStyledDocument().setCharacterAttributes(pozicija, tekst1.getStyledDocument().getLength()+1, tekst1.getStyle("default1"), true);

            if(selektovaniTxt!=null){

                //selektovan=true;
                //tekst1.replaceSelection("");
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: when you say style do you mean font? text size?

Comment: yes, I mean font, text size ect.

Comment: just to clarify, when you are typing a string in to a jtextpane you only want the last letter in the box to be styled differently

i.e the z at the end would be different the pipe "|" indicates the text cursor?

this_string_is_normalZ|

Comment: if I have one sentance for exemple: My name is Nedim. set in one style, and when i change font in JComboBox, i want that next sentance be in that font, and not to change both sentances.

Comment: I am tryiing to set style for future text entered in my JTextPane, from my cursor position: